# Issue with deleting sheet from excel

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Are there any known issues with deleting sheet from an excel? My code does not allow me to delete first sheet, but do so for any other sheet.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="courses.xls" name="spreadSheetVar">
<cfset spreadsheetRemoveSheet(spreadsheetVar,"first")>
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="courses.xls"  name="spreadsheetVar" overwrite="true" >
```

Courses.xls has two sheets named first & second. If I try to delete "second" it deletes, but while trying deleting "first" it throw error.

environment: coldfusion dev edition 9,0,2,282541
in built IIS, running on window 7 pro
Following is the error it throw

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (1) is out of range
>   (0..0)    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetName(HSSFWorkbook.java:542)
>     at coldfusion.excel.Excel.removeSheet(Excel.java:179)   at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.SpreadSheetRemoveSheet(CFPage.java:6912)    at
>   cftest12ecfm402095173.runPage(C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\Test_Apps\test1.cfm:3)
>     at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)  at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:381)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>     at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>     at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)    at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)    at
>   coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)    at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)    at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at jrun.servlet.http.WebService.invokeRunnable(WebService.java:172)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer, I was looking for. It is just a workaround, if some is stuck and no way forward. It looks like CF treats first sheet as Active sheet and is not able to delete it.
Making any other sheet as active will allow the first sheet to be deleted.
    <cfset SpreadsheetSetActiveSheetNumber(spreadsheetVar, N)>

Where N is anything other than 1.
As I said, until someone who have good hold on java and native POI being used in spreadsheet functions, does not answer this question, this is is the workaround.